# JavaScript - Draw html-mask before high load script execution

Tags: javascript, extjs

i'm using ExtJS. I want to mask my window before highload script will execute. When I use

```
App.mask();
some.high.load.script();
App.unmask();
```

mask doesn't appears. After mask function start highload and then It can't change html until it end. And in that case I need to use defer (setTimeout analog).  Is there any solution without defer methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function defering is only way to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
App.mask();
document.body.offsetHeight;
some.high.load.script();
App.unmask();
```

For more information: http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/:

> script may prevent the browser from optimizing the reflows, and cause
>   it to flush the queue and perform all batched changes. This happens
>   when you request style information, such as
>
> offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight
>   scrollTop/Left/Width/Height clientTop/Left/Width/Height
>   getComputedStyle(), or currentStyle in IE All of these above are
>   essentially requesting style information about a node, and any time
>   you do it, the browser has to give you the most up-to-date value. In
>   order to do so, it needs to apply all scheduled changes, flush the
>   queue, bite the bullet and do the reflow.